# Should restrict url going to Account/Login by default in Asp.net core webapi when using identity and accept Auth0 authentication by default

Tags: reactjs, oauth, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi, auth0

I am using  both Auth0 forlogin and Asp.net core webapi identity (Front end-Reactjs and backend=Asp.net core webapi) and
using an [Authorize] attribute, By default, it is taking identity authentication and it's redirecting to the Account/Login page
Even though I add the default authentication as JwtBearerDefaults in the configuration services

Note: Auth0 authentication is working when I use the [Authorize] attribute in a different solution without identity but when I implement
identity as well then [Authorize] working for identity only not for Auth0

**Should restrict URL going to Account/Login by default in Asp.net core web API when using identity and accept Auth0 authentication by default**

The below code is working for me without using asp.net core identity

**Configureservices**

```
    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
               
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://xxxxxx.uk.auth0.com";
                options.Audience = "xxxxx";
            };
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
       [Authorize]
        public IList<UserDto> Get()
        {
            return _userService.GetUsers();
        }
```

**Expecting:** By default Auth0 authentication should happen even though if I use Asp.net core web API Identity

Comment: Check [this](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/aspnet-core-webapi/01-authorization)

Comment: Have tried this.its working for me without using identity.but when using with identity it's not working

Comment: Did you add two [Authorize]? One for Auth0 and other for Identity

Comment: No have added one [Authorize] only.

Comment: Add two [Authorization]s. One for Auth0. Other for Identity

Comment: Where to add this Authorization whether in configuration service by adding jwt and cookiebased authentication...?or is there any other place to add this.could u pls brief about this.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict the default identity authentication...?

Comment: I can give you authorization using only Auth0 if you want bcz I don't know why you try to use both identity and Auth0, while you can use only Auth0.

Comment: Also, can you share the whole code of `Configureservices`. Then I can point out what was missing

Comment: It's a client requirement need to use both auth0(for login-generating token) and identity to save data in dd.pls give me Authorization using only auth0.i ll take a look on tat

Answer (score 0):

For the Auth0 Authentication Startup.cs should manage like this

**ConfigureServices**

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.Authority = "https://<Your-Domain>.auth0.com/"
                options.Audience =<Client ID>
            });
```

**Configure**

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseCors("AllowAnyCorsPolicy");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions { RequestPath = "/build" });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html", new StaticFileOptions
                {
                    OnPrepareResponse = x =>
                    {
                        var httpContext = x.Context;
                        var path = httpContext.Request.RouteValues["path"];
                        // now you get the original request path
                    }
                });
            });
        }
```

For the further knowledge follow below threads

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-7.0
2. [Using multiple authentication schemes in ASP.NET Core 3.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322812/using-multiple-authentication-schemes-in-asp-net-core-3-1)
3. [ASP.NET Core 6 : add multiple authentication schemes with multiple authorization policies along with dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214521/asp-net-core-6-add-multiple-authentication-schemes-with-multiple-authorization)

Comment: Your below refernece Thread is worked for me .Thanks u so much for ur support and valuable time- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62322812/using-multiple-authentication-schemes-in-asp-net-core-3-1

Comment: Happy to help you. While your question is related to the mentioned thread, I will mark this question as duplicate. Then the future users will find out this thread as a helpful one